# Change a Google app engine project from the flexible to standard environment

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to change a Google app engine project from the flexible to standard environment? I have to keep the existing project ID as it is used as the URL, but I need to change to the standard environment because the flexible one is too expensive.

It is mentioned that one should just delete the resources of the project instead of the project itself. However, I can't find any resources other than the project itself on the 
["Resources" page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LMv5.png).

Or do I just update the app.yaml and update the project?

Many thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the app.yaml is enough to change the environment of app engine.

Keep in mind that some libraries on your Flex environment could depend of additional OS packages installed on your flex environment.

In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#comparing_high-level_features) you could find all differences between environments, if you code meets with the constraints of STD environment, you only need to re deploy your application.

But don't forget to [delete/stop](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/stop) the previous versions of your App Engine service  in order to avoid additional costs.

to stop a version you can use the following command:

`gcloud app versions stop --service [servicename] [version name]`